# Laravel 4 session doesn't expire after lifetime limit

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

I've set `'lifetime' => 10` in my session config file, but it doesn't expire at all.

In laravel 3 with that setting, after logging in, when limit of 10 minutes is exceeded, the session expires properly and user is redirected to login again.

In laravel 4 it doesn't happen. After 10 minutes I can refresh, do anything and still session is valid.

I'm testing both on the same machine with analogical settings... What am I missing?

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with your application, but session `lifetime` is working with me. If your session `driver` is file, make sure that it has write access to `app/storage` folder. For quick test, you can try with `'lifetime' => 1` instead of 10 minutes.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've got it. The problem was with the config pair `lifetime` and `expire_on_close`.

If `expire_on_close` is set to true, laravel 4 will ignore `lifetime`. I had:

```
'lifetime' => 1,
'expire_on_close' => true,
```

and in this case, session was valid after 1 min - it would only expire after closing browser. I changed it to:

```
'lifetime' => 1,
'expire_on_close' => false,
```

and now session is expiring after 1 min. no matter if browser is closed or not - close enough to what I've wanted.

The reason why I was confused and haven't figured it out earlier was that the comments there are unclear in that matter and that in Laravel 3 it worked differently...

Comment: Is this anywhere in the documentation? Really should be. I also ran into the same problem and had no idea what was wrong. I don't agree with the logic from a security point of view, secure apps need the ability to set session cookies that also expire.

Comment: @JonoCoetzee I haven't found it in docs, only comments in config file gave me some hints - all in all I've spent a few hours on testing this behaviour and figured it out. I also agree that it should work better, always allowing to expire the cookie

Comment: also faced the same problem today, but in my case I need to have both supported, session lifetime 8 hours and in case the user closes the browser also destroyed. maybe any info on this theme?

Comment: Thanks. This works for me for laravel 5.1 also. wired problem one.

Comment: Thanks @Tom! This is such a weird issue. I was having the same issues.

Comment: I searched my `vendor/laravel` folder for `expire_on_close` and found only one result. 

The `expire_on_close` config value is used here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php#L203 

This issue (and my own experience) suggests that Tom is right: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9321#issuecomment-113331445

I will offer a pull request to improve the comments at https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.6.33/config/session.php#L23 because the docs (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session#configuration) don't mention this.