# Session expiring but not logging user out in Laravel 5

Tags: session, laravel, laravel-5

I've gone in to the sessions file in the config folder and changed the lifetime = 1 and expire_on_close = false.

I've gone in to the php.ini and commented out session.gc_maxlifetime.

Anything that I put in to the session variable gets wiped out after x amount of minutes that I set in the config file but I'm still not logged out. Am I supposed to create something that logs me out or is Laravel supposed to log me out automatically?

Comment: If you want the user to be logged out after closing the window you will need expire_on_close set to true.

Comment: I've set the session to expire after 1 minute and the expire_on_close to false because of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24424607/laravel-4-session-doesnt-expire-after-lifetime-limit