# Laravel 5.1 prevent token mismatch after form idle

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel app which has a user membership system, users can register and login.  If I leave the login form idle for a while and then try to login, I get the following error:

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php
```

What's the best way to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure the session lifetime in the file `config/session.php`:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => 15,

'expire_on_close' => false,
```

One thing to have in mind is that, at least in Laravel 4.2, when `expire_on_close` is set to `true` the `lifetime` is [ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24424607/laravel-4-session-doesnt-expire-after-lifetime-limit)